# Passing variables to DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentfilter

I'm creating a custom `DocumentFilter`.

However, I have to use it on several different components. Only difference between them is character limit, which could be changed by changing a single variable.

The question is, how do I pass that variable to `DocumentFilter`?

This is my custom `DocumentFilter` class (most of the code removed):

```
class DefaultDocFilter extends DocumentFilter
{   
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,
         String str, AttributeSet a) 
    {
        //do something with charLimit 
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length,
         String str, AttributeSet a)
    {
        //do something else with charLimit
    }
}
```

Implementation in main code:

```
int charLimit = 40;
doc = (AbstractDocument) JTextArea.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DefaultDocFilter());
```

How do I pass `charLimit` to the `DefaultDocFilter?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add as member variable:

```
class DefaultDocFilter extends DocumentFilter
{   
    private int charLimit = 40;

    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,
         String str, AttributeSet a) 
    {
        //do something with charLimit 
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length,
         String str, AttributeSet a)
    {
        //do something else with charLimit
    }

    public int getCharLimit() {
        return charLimit;
    }

    public void setCharLimit(int charLimit) {
        this.charLimit = charLimit;
    }
}
```

then:

```
doc.setCharLimit(charLimit);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the variable to your subclass.

```
class DefaultDocFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    private final int charLimit;

    public DefaultDocFilter(int charLimit) {
        this.charLimit = charLimit;
    }

    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,
         String str, AttributeSet a) 
    {
        //do something with charLimit 
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length,
         String str, AttributeSet a)
    {
        //do something else with charLimit
    }
}
```

Then when you add the document filter, just construct a new one with your limit:

```
textField.getDocument().setDocumentFilter(new DefaultDocFilter(20));
```